# Connecting to a DC with duplicate IP addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2016

I have 3 Domain controllers in a Windows Server 2016 environment: A-serv01, A-serv02, and A-01. The only two that my team use and are aware of are the "serv" ones. However, one day I ran `nltest` for the domain and found the oddball A-01. Running nslookup on any DC in the Domain says that A-01 and A-serv01 resolve to the same IP address.

My team believes A-01 doesn't exist and is just a leftover DNS artifact from before it was (possibly) renamed to A-serv01. But don't my `nltest` results prove its existence as a unique DC?

How can I prove A-01 actually exists, and how can I demote it without being able to connect to it (due to the IP address conflict)?

Answer (score 2):

If there's a computer account in the domain for A-01 then it exists. If there isn't a computer account in the domain for A-01 then it doesn't exist.

If it doesn't exist then you need to perform a metadata clean up of A-01.

Comment: There is a computer account for it. There's no way this computer account could be an outdated artifact from a DC-renaming, like the DNS record? Keep in mind that the people managing these DC's were not Windows Server experts, so could A-01 have been improperly removed but somehow the computer account persisted?

Comment: @Willman Either check the extended attributes in the computer account for `lastlogontimestamp` etc., or disable it and test your AD again.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way. Since you have two domain controllers, shut down A-serv01 from the console. That will guarantee you are shutting down the correct one. Leave A-serv02 up and running. If A-01 really exists, you should be able to remote into it and demote/shut down or whatever you want with it.